# Get infos returned by a labellink in a richtextbox (.NET FORMS)

Tags: .net, powershell, winforms

I have a problem to get the information returned by my labelLink into a richtextbox.

I've got text in the RichTextBox and I create the Labellink like this.

```
$Textlink = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
$Textlink.text = "AMIGA"
$Textlink.Name = "AMIGALINK"
$Textlink.add_LinkClicked($Textlink_LinkClicked)
$ClassicRTB1.Controls.Add($Textlink)
```

It's adding an AMIGA clickable link in my RichTextBox named $ClassicRTB1

I have done this powershell statement when the button is clicked

```
$Textlink_LinkClicked = {
$ClassicRTB1.Clear()
$message = $_.linktext
$ClassicRTB1.AppendText("$message  `n") }
```

It's well executing the line $ClassicRTB1.Clear() but I have nothing returned into the variable $_ for .linktext :(

I tried a lot of code all the day and found nothing ... Is what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Change `$_.linktext` to `$args[0].linktext` or `$Sender.linktext`

Comment: No it's the same with the both thanks for the try. i'm supposed to receive the $textlink.name ?

Comment: Looks like you'll want `.Text` to get the display text, and [`.Links.LinkData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.links) to get the underlying link values/targets.

Comment: Thanks maybe i'm trying to something à bit complicated for me lol :) i successfully get event Textlink for a link like URL autodetected by the RTB so i think it's my method to create a link that is bad maybe.

Comment: Yeah but in this case you're working with a `LinkLabel`, not an RTF element :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
# This assumes that you've actually assigned a URL to the 
# $TextLink instance - see the bottom section for how to do that.
$Textlink_LinkClicked = {

  # Declare the event delegate's parameters.
  param($evtSender, $evtArgs)

  # Retrieve the target info (typically, a URL) associated 
  # with the link that was clicked.
  $message = $evtArgs.Link.LinkData

  $ClassicRTB1.AppendText("$message  `n") 

}
```

---

Building on Mathias' helpful comments:

- Your primary problem is your **mistaken attempt to refer to the *event sender*** (the link-label object) **via `$_`**, which is the wrong [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) to use.

  - In the simplest case, *use the automatic [**`$this`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this) variable*.
  - Alternatively, given that the script block receives the usual event-delegate arguments - the event's sender and the event's arguments - you can refer to them via the automatic [`$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) variable:

    - `$args[0]` also refers to the event sender, and `$args[1]` to the event arguments.
    - A more descriptive, but more verbose alternative is to *formally declare parameters* for these arguments: `param($evtSender, $evtArgs)`, as shown in the top section.
  - Note:

    - Event-related automatic variables such as [`$Sender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#sender) are *not* available - they only apply to script blocks passed to the `-Action` parameter of the [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) and [`Register-EngineEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent) cmdlets.
- Your secondary problem is that **a [`LinkLabel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel) instance has no `.LinkText` property**.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Instead, such an instance has a *collection* of links stored in the `.Links` property, and each `LinkLabel.Link` element of that collection has a `.Data` property containing the target data (typically, a *URL string*, but technically it can be any object)

    - *One* link is present by default, and here's an example of how you would set it:

      ```
      $Textlink.Links[0].LinkData = 'https://example.org'
      ```
  - Because a single link-label can potentially house *multiple* links - if configured, for multiple *substrings* of its label (`.Text` property) - the robust approach to respond to a click is not to examine the link-label instance *itself*, but to to use the *event arguments* to tell you *which specific link* was actually clicked.

    - The `.Link` property of the event-arguments object passed to the event delegate identifies its specific link, whose `.Data` property contains the link's target.

---

<sup>[1] You may be thinking of the `.LinkText` property of the event-arguments object that is available if you respond to the `LinkClicked` event of a `RichTextBox` instance itself, in response to clicking a link that that instance *itself* provides, due to recognizing raw URLs in its text (and, in .NET (Core), also RTF hyperlinks assigned via `.Rtf`) and turning them into clickable links.</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot ! Now i understand how it's working. thank you for the time you took to explain it, all answers on the internet was for c#. Now it's working have a nice day mklement0

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer is helpful, @Amiga1200; my pleasure.